# 'IConfiguration' does not contain a definition for 'Get'

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-1.0

Originally, I had the code in 1.0.0-rc1-beta6.

```cs
 public static IConfiguration Configuration { get; set; }

 public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env, IApplicationEnvironment appEnv)
    {
        // Setup configuration sources.
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder(appEnv.ApplicationBasePath)
            .AddJsonFile("config.json")
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();
        Configuration = builder.Build();
        var test = Configuration.Get("ASPNET_ENV");
    }
```

Now I want to use 1.0.0-rc1-update, the code is:

```cs
 public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env, IApplicationEnvironment appEnv)
    {
        // Setup configuration sources.
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(appEnv.ApplicationBasePath)
            .AddJsonFile("config.json")
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();
        Configuration = builder.Build();
        var test = Configuration.Get("ASPNET_ENV");
    }
```

"ASP.NET_ENV" is from launchSettings.json file.

```json
"profiles": {
"IIS Express": {
  "commandName": "IISExpress",
  "launchBrowser": true,
  "environmentVariables": {
    "ASPNET_ENV": "Development"
  },
  "sdkVersion": "dnx-clr-win-x64.1.0.0-beta6"
},
```

But I still get the error on the last line.

> 'IConfiguration' does not contain a definition for 'Get' and the best extension method overload 'SessionExtensions.Get(ISession, string)' requires a receiver of type 'ISession'.

Also get the error here.

```cs
   public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // Add MVC services to the services container.
        services.AddMvc(); //error
    }
```

My project.json file

```json
    {
  "webroot": "wwwroot",
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS": "1.0.0-beta7",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Tooling.Razor": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Framework.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0-beta8",
    "Microsoft.Framework.Logging": "1.0.0-beta8",
    "Microsoft.Framework.Logging.Console": "1.0.0-beta8",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0-rc1-final",
    "EntityFramework": "6.1.3",
    "jqGridWebApi": "1.1.4",
    "EnyimMemcached": "2.13.0",
    "xunit": "2.2.0-beta1-build3239",
    "Moq": "4.2.1510.2205",
    "NLog": "2.1.0",
    "CryptSharpOfficial": "2.1.0",
    "System.Linq.Dynamic": "1.0.4"
  },
  "commands": {
    "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting --server Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener --server.urls http://localhost:5001",
    "kestrel": "Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting --server Kestrel --server.urls http://localhost:5005"
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": {
      "frameworkAssemblies": {
        "System.configuration": "4.0.0.0",
        "System.Data": "4.0.0.0"
      }
    }
  },
  "exclude": [
    "wwwroot",
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components"
  ],
  "publishExclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components",
    "**.xproj",
    "**.user",
    "**.vspscc"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "prepublish": [ "npm install", "bower install", "gulp clean", "gulp min" ]
  },
  "configurations": {
    "Staging": { }
  }
}
```

Comment: try GetValue() or GetValue<T>()

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45039136/bind-a-iconfigurationsection-to-an-complex-object-without-aspnetcore

Answer (score 188):

Install the NuGet package:

`Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder`

Duplicate: [Bind an IConfigurationSection to a complex object without ASP.NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45039136/bind-a-iconfigurationsection-to-an-complex-object-without-aspnetcore)

[image: Screenshot of NuGet packages]

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, since it directly answers the question asker's question.

Comment: Note that you don't need to have a using clause for Binder, just for `using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;`

Comment: This wasn't quite enough for me, the configuration object had been constructor injected using `Configuration`, not `IConfiguration`. So the error was correct, but cause was a subtle typo.

Answer (score 8):

The Get method does not exist anymore. You have to use:

```cs
Configuration.GetSection("key").Value.ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

For RC1, the NuGet package for configuration is in `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json` instead of `Microsoft.Framework.Configuration.Json`.

```cs
public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env,  IApplicationEnvironment appEnv)
{
    // Setup configuration sources.
    var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(appEnv.ApplicationBasePath)
        .AddJsonFile("config.json", false)
        .AddEnvironmentVariables();
    Configuration = builder.Build();
    var test = Configuration.Get<string>("ASPNET_ENV");
}
```