# Bind an IConfigurationSection to a complex object without ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, json, configuration, .net-core, .net-core-1.1

I have a .NET Core console application and want to read the `appsettings.json` and parse a section as `List<Param>` (without Dependency Injection or ASP.NET Core).
I already tried [How do I bind a multi level configuration object using IConfiguration in a .net Core application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41369996/how-do-i-bind-a-multi-level-configuration-object-using-iconfiguration-in-a-net) but it seems like `.Get<T>()` got removed from `netcoreapp1.1`

```
IConfigurationSection myListConfigSection = configurationRoot.GetSection("ListA");

List<Param> paramList;

//Get does not exist
//paramList = myListConfigSection.Get<Param>();

string paramListJson = myListConfigSection.Value // is null
// won't work neither because paramListJson is null
paramList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Param>(paramListJson);
```

appsettings.json:

```
{
  "ListA": [
    { "ID": "123", "Param": "ABC"},
    { "ID": "123", "Param": "JKS"},
    { "ID": "456", "Param": "DEF"}
  ]
}
```

Is there an easy way to load the config into the object or do I have to read the config file again and parse it myself with `JsonConvert`?

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36694099/iconfiguration-does-not-contain-a-definition-for-get

Answer (score 113, accepted):

`Get<T>` is defined in package `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder`

Comment: Thanks, it did the trick. As much I love it, I sometimes hate that they switched everything to a different nkpg.

Comment: #loveHate  Yep,I'm always searching for and finding that "extra" nkpg.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be the same as GetSection as it appears to get the entire config file as an object.

Comment: You can use it an on IConfiguratoinSection and get just this section as an object