# IConfiguration: unexpected GetValue behavior

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

`GetValue<T>` returns null instead of building the object. Meanwhile, `GetSection` of the same key works as expected.

Expected result: `GetValue` does not return null, instead it creates a new instance of the `ApiConfig` class, filled with the info that is in the `IConfiguration` object. According to [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45039316/831138) it looks like the correct way to achieve what I am trying to do.

```
public static void Test(IConfiguration configuration)
{
    var key = "Authentication:ApiConfig";

    var children = configuration.GetSection(key).GetChildren().ToList();
    // SUCCEEDED: children.Count == 3 (Url, Username and Password)

    var config1 = configuration.GetValue<ApiConfig>(key);
    // FAILED: config1 == null

    var config2 = configuration.GetSection("Authentication").GetValue<ApiConfig>("ApiConfig");
    // FAILED: config2 == null
}

public class ApiConfig
{
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

Project info:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  ...

</Project>
```

Comment: Try `configuration.GetSection("Authentication").Get<ApiConfig>("ApiConfig");`

Comment: @ChrisPickford It worked, with a modification: `Get<T>()` does not accept the path as a parameter, so the full path must be added in the `GetSection(key)` method. This is the final code: `var config = configuration.GetSection("Authentication:ApiConfig").Get<ApiConfig>();`. Thank you !

Comment: Uh, no, that is NOT what the linked answer says.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the correct way to do this is, is using [`ConfigurationBinder.Bind`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration.configurationbinder.bind) (As described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/#bind-hierarchical-configuration-data-using-the-options-pattern))

```cs
var apiConfig = new ApiConfig();
configuration.GetSection("Authentication:ApiConfig").Bind(apiConfig);
```

edit. seems like

```cs
configuration.GetSection("Authentication").Bind("ApiConfig", apiConfig);
```

should also work.